# Cookie only sets when NOT using JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cookies

I am creating cookies using [jQuery cookie](https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/), which are setting when I don't use `JSON.stringify` as in the following:

```
$.cookie("previousObject", savedObjs);
```

but which do not set when I use `JSON.stringify()`, as in the following:

```
$.cookie("previousStories", JSON.stringify(savedObjs));
```

I have also tried the following:

```
$.cookie.json = true;
$.cookie("previousObject", savedObjs);
```

The cookie that should be being created logs to the console,but when I look under `resources` in the browser, there are no cookies there.

How do I make these cookies work?

Comment: Is there an error in the console?

Comment: @epascarello no errors...it logs with `"previousStories=` plus the stringified object

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your usage.  Make sure you *open* the Cookies section under resources, it will be tucked under the host name of your site.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to explicitly stringify an object before passing it to `$.cookie()` since the latter does this for you automatically anyway.

Here's the part of its code that encodes your value:

```
function stringifyCookieValue(value) {
    return encode(config.json ? JSON.stringify(value) : String(value));
}
```

So your last bit of code is actually right:

```
$.cookie.json = true;
$.cookie("previousObject", savedObjs);
```

In Firefox you can find your cookies in Storage Inspector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector#Cookies

Chrome shows them in Resources: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/resource-panel#cookies